# What WIFI driver for WIFI RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader MSI GT75VR 7RF Titan Pro to use on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless, msi

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. My WIFI used to work, but after the upgrade I am not able to use the Wifi Card any longer.
The computer is a MSI GT75VR 7RF Titan Pro laptop
The Wifi card is a **Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader**, judging from the output of `lspci`.
I understand from previous questions that ubuntu 20.04 may not support it by default and it is necessary to download the driver, but I haven't managed to understand which one is right for me. Can you help me understand that?

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation CM238 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1080 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation NVMe Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Aquantia Corp. AQC107 NBase-T/IEEE 802.3bz Ethernet Controller [AQtion] (rev 02)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3f:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation NVMe Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader` is not a Wi-Fi card. It is a card reader. If you are asking about a built-in adapter, it is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

It magically began working today after reboot. I am nos rue what I did.